# Xlim and Ylim arguments in R don't work, Ordiplot

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am currently doing ordination analysis on vegetation data in R, in particular using NMDS. I am having a very difficult time with setting the xlim and ylim. In the documentation, it claims there is functionality for this provided in the ordiplot function by simpliy using xlim = and ylim =.

The code I am using is here:
Code to create an NMDS containing plots of a current grassland survey, and plots which were previously recorded in the same location (quasi-permanent monitoring points):
`NMDS_survey1 <- metaMDS(ISGvsSGData, k = 4, trymax = 100, trace = F, autotransform = TRUE, distance = "bray")`

My data layout is species as columns, with plots as rows, and abundances recorded in % cover.

Code to plot the NMDS, and an attempt to display my plots (although very cluttered at the moment):
`ordiplot(NMDS_survey1, type = "n", xlim = c(-4,4)) orditorp(NMDS_survey1, display = "sites", cex = 1.1, air = 0.01)`

The plot output is attached, as seen, the xlim hasn't changed.

I am not getting any error codes regarding the xlim.

I expected the xlim to be reduced to -3.5 and 3.5, to hopefully make the figure more interpretable. I've tried other forums, R documentation, worked examples and the issue hasn't been resolved. I also could not come across a question which had similar behaviours to my issue.

Comment: Perhaps ordiplot is not a base plotting function? If it’s in the ggplot paradigm there would be a different mechanism. You should include `library` calls for the needed packages.